# Cannot restore my Dell Inspiron N5110 to Factory Settings

Tags: windows-7, laptop, dell-inspiron, factory-defaults

I have a Dell Inspiron N5110 that runs Windows 7 Home Premium, that's about 3 years old.

When I first got it, it had problems with the Bluetooth Driver, so Dell Tech Support made me format drive C:\ and made me reinstall Windows using the Windows CD that ships with it.

Since then, I haven't been able to restore the PC to Factory Settings, no matter what I've tried.

I can see the RECOVERY drive when I open disk management, but can't get to whats on it.

Dell Tech Support told me that it wasn't possible to do so because of formatting the C: drive.

I recently tried using Repair System, but somehow don't get the options other guys get (like Dell Data Safe etc.)

Any idea how I can restore my Laptop to Factory Settings?

[image: Disk Management]

[image: Repair System 1]

[image: Repair System 2]

[image: Repair System 3]

[image: Repair System 4]

Comment: Download a Windows 7 installation disk and install Windows 7.  You won't be able to use the factory restoration.  There is very little difference between a factory restoration and installing it from the installation disk.

Comment: have you tried from inside windows with DELL recovery software?

Comment: In disk management mark the Recovery partition as Active, reboot and see if it loads Dell Recovery, if it does do a factory restore.